# CentOS bashrc function to email on login

Tags: linux, bash, email, centos, scp

I've a system setup where an email is sent on a user login (line from .bashrc):

```
printf "user details, ip etc" | mail -s "[LOGIN NOTICE] `hostname` - `whoami`" <admin>@<domain>.co.uk
```

This works, I'm looking to make it a little smarter. it will email on any login, even on a SCP transfer. Can anyone suggest how I can detect and exclude SCP or TTY etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is sourced whenever a new shell is started – regardless of whether
the shell is interactive, a sub-shell of an existing Bash shell, etc.
I presume what you want is to check whether or not the login shell is
interactive or not:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
    printf "user details, ip etc" | mail -s "[LOGIN NOTICE] `hostname` - `whoami`" <admin>@<domain>.co.uk
fi
```

A portable (non-Bash specific) way to check if the shell being started is
interactive or not would be:

```
case "$-" in
    *i*)    printf "user details, ip etc" | mail -s "[LOGIN NOTICE] `hostname` - `whoami`" <admin>@<domain>.co.uk
esac
```

See [GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html).

This [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch) also has some relevant answers.